# How to get the Value of an ID from a TR of a Clicked TD Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamically created table as:

```
<div id="gameListDiv">
<table id="gameListTable">
    <tr id="1">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td class="tpButton">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td class="tpButton">F</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I have a listener:

```
$('#gameListDiv').on('click','.tpButton', function(toggleThisTP) {
    // If user clicks C, return the row ID of '1'
    // if user clicks F, return the row ID Of '2'
});
```

As in the code comments just above, how to I get the value if the ID tag of the specific row when the user clicks a cell in the 3rd column of the table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```js
$('#gameListDiv').on('click','.tpButton', function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gameListDiv">
<table id="gameListTable">
    <tr id="1">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td class="tpButton">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td class="tpButton">F</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

[Link to closest() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Worked like a champ - thank you.  Coming from Delphi/Pascal .EXE work, the transition has been a bit foreign :).  If not too inappropriate an aside question:  Why does neither $('.tpButton).on('click'. . .  or $('#gameListTable).on('click', '.tpButton'. . .  work?

Comment: @Dan A, Are we still talking about the same code? Because I made a snippet with that code and it works.

Comment: The code works great (as did your original answer post).  Thank you!

Comment: I just tried it in the snippet (but I didn't save the changed, because than the answer wouldn't fit with your question) and it worked like a charm, so I don't know why it does not work on your end. I'm sorry! Maybe with an example (online) I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#gameListDiv').on('click','.tpButton', function(toggleThisTP) {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id = row.attr('id');
});
```

Comment: I'm curious: why do you choose closest() over parent()? I always want to be sure what I select, not hope that it is closest to my selection.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan, the difference between closest/parent is closest can go many levels up until it reaches the selector. Alot of time, you will have nested elements and want to reach some grandparent, so Im just used to using it. But, parent would have worked just as well in this case

Comment: And it seems to be [quicker](https://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/2) Thanks for the opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Class

```
<div id="gameListDiv">
<table id="gameListTable">
    <tr class="gamelist" id="1">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td class="tpButton">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gamelist" id="2">
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td class="tpButton">F</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".gamelist").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
   alert(id);
});
```

Comment: This example looks like I would get a click event regardless of the cell.  I'm only interested in the user clicking on the 3rd column of cells.  But frankly, I'm so green, I could be wrong :)